# Processing columns inside SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following sample data:

```
id, user_id, action, date, item_id
(5, 1, 'created', '2016-09-08, 1),
(6, 1, 'sold', '2016-09-14, 1),
(7, 2, 'created', '2016-09-08, 2),
(8, 2, 'sold', '2016-09-30, 2),
(9, 3, 'created', '2016-10-08, 3)
```

I'm trying to create a Query that returns the percentage of items sold within 1 week. The value of the `column: "action"` represents if the item has been put up for sale, or sold. How could this look?. Should I do this by using a subquery or?

Expected result should be a single percentage (the number of items sold within 1 week, of the total number of items created).

Comment: Add expected results based on the example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data is indeed this simple, this can easily be done by joining the same table to itself. The first reference to the sample data can be aliased as `created` and will filter to items with an action of `created`. Likewise, the `sold` table reference will restrict itself to items with an action of `sold`.

Once that's done, we'll get a row of data that has an item's creation and sold dates. Anything that doesn't have a sold action is simply discarded by an inner join. The built in function `datediff(date1, date2)` will give us the number of days between our two dates. If this is less than or equal to 7, you know that it was sold within a week.

```sql
select
    created.id
    , created.user_id
    , created.item_id
    , datediff(created.date, sold.date) as days_to_sell
from
    sample_data created
    join sample_data sold
        on created.item_id = sold.item_id
where
    created.action  = 'created'
    and sold.action = 'sold'
    and datediff(created.date, sold.date) <= 7
```

Comment: Super handy with the days_to_sell column. If I were to change to a single percentage (the number of users that sold their item within 1 week, after creating it). How would that work?

Comment: That'd require a left join and a case statement for starters. That's a bit detailed and should be done as a new question if you need help with that. Feel free to reply with a link to the new question if you ask it. :)

Comment: It actually was in the original question :) isn't it kind of stupid to create a new thread for that?